# @Azure/M365 Legends - How to query ACTIVE Azure AD Guest Users that has EMPLOYEE TYPE as "Something" using KQL in Azure Log Analytics? Thanks all

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, log-analysis

@Log Analytics (Azure Monitoring)

@Azure/M365 Legends - How to query ACTIVE Azure AD Guest Users that has EMPLOYEE TYPE as "Something" using KQL in Azure Log Analytics? Thanks all.

I tried using the below but it doesn't bring up the accurate result.

```
SigninLogs
| search "Something"
| where UserType == "Guest"
| project UserDisplayName
```

Answer (score 0):

Followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/signinlogs) and I have reproduced in my environment and got below results:

Firstly, I have tested below command to check if I am getting Logs or not:

```
SigninLogs
| where UserType contains "Guest"
|project  UserDisplayName
```

And I got logs as below:

[image]

Then I checked the attributes of `SinginLogs` using below command:

```
SigninLogs
| where UserType contains "Guest"
```

[image]

I have observed that in SigninLogs there is No Attribute Called `EmployeeType` And you can also Check [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/signinlogs) to verify that.

So You cannot filter on Users based on employeetype in `SinginLogs` of Azure AD.